# JWTRefreshTokenBundle, Class gesdinet.jwtrefreshtoken does not exist

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I get refresh token but when I call jwt refresh path response is 500 (Class gesdinet.jwtrefreshtoken does not exist. (500 Internal Server Error)) 
composer.json

```
`"require"` : {
        "php" : ">=7.1",
        "symfony/symfony" : "3.4.*",
        "doctrine/orm" : "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle" : "^1.3",
        ....
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.4",
        "gesdinet/jwt-refresh-token-bundle": "^0.5.2"
    },
```

the configuration is identical to the documentation, anyone can help?
https://github.com/gesdinet/JWTRefreshTokenBundle#jwtrefreshtokenbundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was mistake in documentation,

```
# app/config/routing.yml
gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token:
    path:     /api/token/refresh
    defaults: { _controller: gesdinet.jwtrefreshtoken::refresh }
# ...
```

we need single colon:

```
defaults: { _controller: gesdinet.jwtrefreshtoken:refresh }
```

https://github.com/gesdinet/JWTRefreshTokenBundle/issues/116

Answer (score 0):

Please try to delete your cache,
launch on your CLI:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Be sure to have added the bundle into your kernel (it depends if you are using symfony 3 or 4)

Comment: Isn't working. I get access to gesdinet.jwtrefreshtoken by container so all classes are properly loaded.